# Pymodis downloading?

Tags: python, modis, spyder, pymodis

I'm trying to download and process MODIS imagery using pymodis.  I have Python 2.7.8 (Spyder), numpy 1.9.1 and gdal 1.11.1.  I've also installed WXPython.

I originally tried to use the modis_download.py script, but continued to get

> `SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax` despite using the formatting recommended
>   in the pymodis documentation:

```
modis_download.py -r -p MOD13Q1.005 -t h18v03 -f 2008-01-01 -e 2008-01-31 \modis_test
```

I'm now trying to call the pymodis.downmodis.downModis module to download MODIS data from the LP DAAC HTTP server.  This seems to be reaching the survey, but returns blank .txt and .log files:

```
pymodis.downmodis.downModis('E:\modis_test', url = 'http://e4ftI01.cr.usgs.gov', tiles = 'h26v08, h25v08', path = 'MOLT', product = 'MOD13Q1.005', today = '2014-01-01', enddate = '2014-02-02', debug = True)
```

Anyone familiar with pymodis that can lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

Recently an updated, improved version of pyMODIS got published:

http://www.pymodis.org/info.html#how-to-install-pymodis

Please consider to update your installation (see above for instructions). Hopefully the problem is solved then. Otherwise please contact the author.